# C LoadLibrary in a loop

Tags: c, loadlibrary

I try to loop over a directory and load functions from several dll files. Every dll file only exports a function with the same name as the dll. The problem is, it loads only the first file.

```
DIR *d;
struct dirent *dir;
d = opendir(".");
if(d) {
    while((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL) {
        // split filename into 'name', 'ext' and 'fullname'
        // '.', '..' and all unliked files are sorted out correctly
        HINSTANCE ext_dll = LoadLibrary(fullname);
        if(NULL != ext_dll) {
            MYPROC ext_func = (MYPROC) GetProcAddress(ext_dll, name);
        }
        ext_dll = NULL;
    }
}
```

However, when i just write it twice it works.

```
HINSTANCE ext_dll = LoadLibrary("ext1.dll");
if(NULL != ext_dll) {
    MYPROC ext_func = (MYPROC) GetProcAddress(ext_dll, "ext1");     
}
ext_dll = LoadLibrary("ext2.dll");
if(NULL != ext_dll) {
    MYPROC ext_func = (MYPROC) GetProcAddress(ext_dll, "ext2");    
}
```

Is there something wrong with my code or is LoadLibrary not meant to be used that way?

Thanks

Comment: What are you doing about directories, like `.` and `..`?

Comment: I sort all of that out when i just print the names its correct. I edit the question.

Comment: This somehow looks like a mixture of Windows code (`LoadLibrary` etc) and Linux code (`readdir`). How is that happening?

Comment: readdir just came up first in my mind. But thats not the error for sure..

Comment: Well if this isn't the actual code but more of a stand-in for it, then can you show the actual code? It's not as if `LoadLibrary` can sense that you used it from inside a loop

Comment: I dont know why you dont beliefe me and ask me for a proof but here https://pastebin.com/J6DRqdZD

Comment: @NoOb It's not about the belief or a proof. It's about https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @NoOb Because the problem is not necessarily where you think it is. This one here is a good example of such a case.

Comment: @dxiv This is such a case that rises the question "shouldn't you, the developer, read the documentation of the methods / libraries you're using?" 5min reads: [strtok](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html) and [readdir](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/readdir.html). @NoOb then you see where the problem is. Try backing up `dir->d_name` pointer before using it in `strtok`, and use that new pointer to send to `strtok`, not the original.

Comment: Sry, i realy thought, that a stupid strtok isnt relevant because i used printf to print it out and everything seemed ok. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP's [linked code](https://pastebin.com/J6DRqdZD) (though not the posted one) includes the following.

```
    d = opendir(".");
    setvoidfunc = (MYSETVOIDPROC) GetProcAddress(dll, "setVoidCallBack");
    if (d) {
        while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL) {
            char *tok = strtok(dir->d_name, ".");
            if(NULL == tok)
                continue;
```

The `strtok` call (potentially) modifies the `dir->d_name` buffer, which violates the Open Group requirement for [`readdir`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/readdir.html).

> *The application shall not modify the structure to which the return value of readdir() points*, ***nor any storage areas pointed to by pointers within the structure.***

Because of the violation, everything that happens after the first time `dir->d_name` gets modified is undefined by the standard and implementation dependent.

Comment: Such a stupid mistake =( Thank you for that, it works now!

Comment: I think about rewriting the whole question because i think right now most people who find this post will have another problem (like me) than loading a library. Is is ok to do so?

Comment: @NoOb `another problem` Then you should post a different question, and perhaps edit this one to add a link to the other question, explaining how/why they are related. Changing existing questions is discouraged, especially *after* being answered.